# One Click Browse the Web For Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer

What is the shortest possible path to make IE 8 in Windows Server 2008 let me browse web sites without asking me confirmation for every other thing I do (Other then installing a different browser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the root of the Service Manager navigation pane, and under the Server Summary click Configure IE ESC, which is part of the Security Information section. A dialog box appears, letting Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration be enabled/disable separately for normal users and administrators.

Disabling the Enhanced Security Configuration will allow you to browse without being prompted.